# Maven build successful but .class files not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven-2

I am using Maven 2.2.1. I have an enterprise java maven project which I am trying to build. When I run `mvn clean install` the EAR is generated. No compilation errors are found. In the logs I get the message that 1980 source files are compiled to ApplicationWeb\target\classes directory. But I cannot find these class files in the location and they are not present in WAR. How to solve this ?

**Edit:** When built from Eclipse using Maven plugin, its working fine. It gives issue when run from Windows Command Prompt. Why the difference ?

Comment: Perhaps the classes are generated in a different location?  You could search the file system for the classes.

Comment: The path is proper. I checked in the logs.

Comment: Do you mean you do not find the classes anywhere in the file system after a command-line mvn run despite console indicating 1980 source files are compiled? Then perhaps they are deleted by subsequent goals. Try mvn compile to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sort of thing usually happens when you're using a different version of Maven. I'm betting your Eclipse is using 3.x which is the in built version.

You have 2 choices:

1. Make Eclipse use the same version as your command line
2. Install a new version of Maven. (3.0.3 is the latest)

I'd recommend upgrading Maven to the latest and getting both your command line and Eclipse to use the same installed version.

Comment: Yes. Looks like Eclipse uses version 3. I have never experienced this in Maven 2.2.1 before. Is there any way to resolve this issue in Maven 2.2.1 ?

Comment: Not sure, the intracies on maven plugin versions and compatability make that difficult. If possible I would use version 3.

Comment: The wierder part is, in some systems it works and some others it wont.

Comment: Yes. It works with version 3. But since this is an enterprise project I dont have liberty to change the version. How is it building fine with 2.2.1 version on other system ?

Comment: There must be some change in your system or the plugins you're using.

Answer (score 0):

as a first attempt to resolve this issue - try to go to your war module (you should have a module responsible for WAR generation) and see whether the files are there.
The ear module is just an "envelope" here - it just takes the war and puts it inside the ear.
So I believe if the issue really exists its in the WAR module's pom file and not in EAR's one.
Check the size of your generated war, check the war plugin configurations as well.

In general this situation shouldn't happen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. I was talking about the same WAR. The size must be 26MB but it is 24MB. Also, observed something. Modified initial question.